# URLRewrite in .htaccess - convert last "-" in a "/"

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm migrating a website to a new CMS, and I had to provide custom redirects for old permalink.
I solved the classic "pageId=x" rewrite+redirect with a custom PHP script that reads in a key-value store the new slug given the old id.

But, I also have various articles that already have a rewritten URL like: `/my-slug-page/`. Most of them should not be rewritten, except for multipage articles that have a structure like: `/my-multipage-article/`, `/my-multipage-article-2/`, `/my-multipage-article-3/`, etc. (the last digit after the last `-` is the page number).

I have to rewrite these links to: `/my-multipage-article/2/`, `/my-multipage-article/3/` etc.
Can I do this directly in the .htaccess with a standard regex parsing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-(\d+)/?$ /$1/$2/ [L]
```